# Datetime fails to save but without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I try saving a row that has an attribute named `class_datetime` (which is a `DateTime`) and it silently fails. Here's an example:

I create a new `LittleClassSession`, like so:

```
irb(main):010:0> l = LittleClassSession.new
=> #<LittleClassSession id: nil, length: nil, class_datetime: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, little_class_id: nil, location_id: nil, session_series_token: nil>
```

The `class_datetime` is a `DateTime`:

```
irb(main):011:0> LittleClassSession.columns_hash["class_datetime"].type
=> :datetime
```

I set the attribute:

```
irb(main):012:0> l.class_datetime = DateTime.now
=> 2015-08-13 22:02:09 -0400
```

And I save (no validations yet):

```
irb(main):013:0> l.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "little_class_sessions" ("class_datetime", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["class_datetime", "2015-08-13 22:02:09.976030"], ["created_at", "2015-08-13 22:03:01.255911"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-13 22:03:01.255911"]]
   (2.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Looks like it worked. Let's see what I saved:

```
irb(main):014:0> l
=> #<LittleClassSession id: 728, length: nil, class_datetime: "2015-08-14 02:02:09", created_at: "2015-08-14 02:03:01", updated_at: "2015-08-14 02:03:01", little_class_id: nil, location_id: nil, session_series_token: nil>
```

Let's see what's in the table:

```
irb(main):015:0> LittleClassSession.last
  LittleClassSession Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "little_class_sessions".* FROM "little_class_sessions"   ORDER BY "little_class_sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<LittleClassSession id: 728, length: nil, class_datetime: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, little_class_id: nil, location_id: nil, session_series_token: nil>
```

My LittleClassSession model looks like:

```
class LittleClassSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :little_class
  belongs_to :location
end
```

What could be causing this? Recently I changed the default timezone in `application.rb`, but I don't see why that might be the reason.

Comment: Try `#save!` and see if it throws any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue went away once I removed these two lines from `application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

This evidently caused some chaos.

Comment: Is someone able to explain what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your `:date_time` field is `DateTime` object.

Try this:

```
l.class_datetime = DateTime.now
```

Rather than:

```
l.class_datetime = Time.now
```

Comment: I tried this with no change. It's still saving `nil`.

Comment: Can you paste your `little_class_session` model code?